# Convert vertical reference to horizontal reference

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I have the problem that I have horizontal input data and I would like to use selected cells, which are in a vertical format, and for example simply calculate two vertical cells.

At the moment I am typing in every cell by hand, because the locking of the colum works only if pulled in the same direction.

I tried to fix the cell with f.ex.: `$A1`, but this does not work.

Please see my example:

[image]

Any recommendation how I could do that automatically in excel?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try

=INDEX($A$1:$A$9,COLUMN(A1))+INDEX($B$1:$B$9,COLUMN(A1))

copy across

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This formula can do the trick:

```
=INDIRECT("A"&COLUMN(A1))+INDIRECT("B"&COLUMN(A1))
```

Put it in the first cell and copy the cell to the next columns.

Comment: Indirect() is volatile and will cause a recalculation of the whole workbook when any cell changes. Volatile functions can cause workbook slowness. Use them only if you like staring at a slowly ticking "Calculating -- 21%"  message every time you edit a cell.